# Spring boot java process doesn't die after shutdown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I can't really tell if this is more related to the OS, Spring, or Hikari.

I'm attempting to shutdown my spring boot application by calling the /actuator/shutdown service. Everything proceeds fine other than the Hikari Database Connection Pools seem to cause exceptions. I've read that these are harmless tomcat warnings that can be ignored, but in my case they seem to be preventing the java process from stopping gracefully.

After the last message in the logs below the java process is still active, which I can confirm via  the "ps" command and by the fact that the log files still seem to have handles open.

```
2023-05-02T11:59:32.668 [Thread-1686] INFO  com.bioclinica.cdi.web.AppShutdownHook - Spring container is shutting down.
2023-05-02T11:59:32.669 [Thread-1686] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_ppdl-ap-t-011682541834402 shutting down.
2023-05-02T11:59:32.669 [Thread-1686] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_ppdl-ap-t-011682541834402 paused.
2023-05-02T11:59:33.064 [Thread-1686] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_ppdl-ap-t-011682541834402 shutdown complete.
2023-05-02T11:59:33.112 [Thread-1686] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
2023-05-02T11:59:33.112 [Thread-1686] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-05-02T11:59:33.161 [Thread-1686] INFO  o.a.c.c.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-02T11:59:33.191 [Thread-1686] WARN  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase - The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@16.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1661)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1056)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1116)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.191 [Thread-1686] WARN  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase - The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-2 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@16.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1661)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1056)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1116)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
 java.base@16.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.202 [Thread-1686] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Stopping ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
2023-05-02T11:59:33.241 [Thread-1686] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Destroying ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
2023-05-02T11:59:33.489 [Thread-1686] INFO  o.s.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2023-05-02T11:59:33.490 [Thread-1686] INFO  o.s.o.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'pacs.db'
2023-05-02T11:59:33.491 [Thread-1686] INFO  o.s.o.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'app.db'
2023-05-02T11:59:33.492 [Thread-1686] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-02T11:59:33.492 [Thread-1686] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Before shutdown stats (total=2, active=0, idle=2, waiting=0)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.496 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6bcf7ddf: (connection evicted)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.497 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@33cc5b50: (connection evicted)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.499 [Thread-1686] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After shutdown stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.499 [Thread-1686] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-05-02T11:59:33.499 [Thread-1686] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-02T11:59:33.499 [Thread-1686] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-2 - Before shutdown stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.499 [HikariPool-2 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-2 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2e6bdbbd: (connection evicted)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.499 [HikariPool-2 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-2 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1215408d: (connection evicted)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.500 [HikariPool-2 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-2 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7b941fe2: (connection evicted)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.500 [HikariPool-2 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-2 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@49661b55: (connection evicted)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.500 [HikariPool-2 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-2 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@441906e5: (connection evicted)
2023-05-02T11:59:33.500 [HikariPool-2 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-2 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2ce4f55f: (connection evicted)
```

Comment: These are warnings. I highly doubt this has anything to do with improper shutdown. The DB pool may need more time or else need to be configured for force kill.

Comment: ^ those are not the complete logs. Probably later the application managed to shut down all hikariPool connections and continue to the shutdown.